# Is there a formal word for when one or more words line up, but are on different lines?

Tags: typography

Not entirely sure if this is the best place to ask, but I've always wondered if there is actually a word for this. In the image below, the words "this is" line up. Sometimes this happens when I'm writing notes for my classes, and I vaguely remember hearing somewhere that this was something that typographers would avoid doing. Is there a word for when this occurs, or am I mistaken?

[image]

Comment: Circumlocution could be one among many possibilities.

Comment: @RamPillai: No it couldn't. I think you have must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @TonyK: Waiting for the right from you. Again, reading a comment before commenting on a comment is important.